# Copying multiple pieces of text and pasting separately

Tags: copy, paste

Me and my friends like to mess around on CS:GO, and what we mostly do is spawn props/watermelons etc. In order to actually spawn the props you type a fairly long and difficult piece of text(string?) into the cmd. ex:prop_physics_create /props_junk/watermelon01.mdl. So to my actual question - could I copy and paste, lets say, these four strings:

```
1. prop_physics_create /props_junk/watermelon01.mdl
2. ent_create /props_junk/wood_crate001a.mdl
3. prop_physics_create /props_junk/watermelon01.mdl
4. prop_dynamic_create /props/cs_militia/toilet.mdl
```

and save them as different variables?? (im an extreme newb, sorry if this isnt proper programmer slang) like string1, string2, string3, etc etc etc, and use CTRL + V + a number on the number pad that corresponds to the string? ex: string1 - CTRL + V + NumPad1?

This is how I imagine it could work, but not with the proper "coding".

```
string1=""
string2=""
string3=""
string4=""
```

(copy some text)

```
if string'x' char count = 0 set string'x' to the copied text
else set copied text to string'x'


on key press CTRL + V + NumPad'x' paste string 'x'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used autohotkey for this type of thing in the past. You will need to script it still. Here is something to start from.
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24677-multiple-copy-and-paste-tool/

**UPDATE:**
First install [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and let it create a sample script under my documents. Then open the sample script in an editor and read the comments at the top to understand what its sample commands do and then double click on the .ahk file to run it (an icon will appear in the task tray for it). Try out the sample hot keys it has in the sample script. This will help you understand what AHK is and how it works. After that, add this text to the script. It is from the post i linked to above:

```
^1::
Send ^c
ClipWait
Clip1 := ClipBoardAll
return
!1::
ClipBoard := Clip1
Send ^v
return
```

Then right click on the task tray icon and choose "reload this script".

The following is setting up a key binding for CTRL + 1.

```
^1::
```

The lines between that and the first return are responsible for copying selected text and holding onto them in a variable called Clip1. When you press CTRL + 1, it executes CTRL + C and then assigns what was copied to the Clip1 variable for later.

```
Send ^c
```

After that, this next part sets up a key binding for ALT + 1.

```
!1::
```

The lines between that and return are responsible for pasting data previously stored in Clip1. It does this by copying Clip1 to the ClipBoard and then executing CTRL + V when you press ALT + 1

```
Send ^v
```

For numbers 2-9 just copy / paste the above over and over changing the numbers. Then right click the task tray icon and reload the script. This is binding copy/paste to CTRL + 1 / ALT + 1, CTRL + 2 / ALT + 2, ... etc... You mentioned different key bindings above and this is all customizable so you can [bind the script to other keys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

I just realized this is a windows specific answer. If you are using Linux, there is are similar programs called [auto key](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) and [IronAHK](https://github.com/polyethene/IronAHK). I haven't used either of those, but have heard that they work on Linux.

Comment: Ive never used AHK before, id prefer something in C++.. if you have a chance could you explain how that script works? Its baffling me right now lol

Comment: So if im understanding this correctly - CTRL + 1 will copy the text then ALT + 1 will paste the text, CTRL + 2, ALT + 2, etc etc?

Comment: Yes. It will only behave this way if you have AHK installed and are running your script. Check the task tray to see that. If this works for you, could you hit the check mark next to my answer to accept it?